# Custom time increments for Kintone's time fields

Tags: javascript, css

In Kintone, the time field currently increments by 30 minutes, but is there a way with JavaScript to change this increment, say, by 10 minute increments?

I know this doesn't fit well with Kintone's JavaScript coding guidelines, but would changing the DOM structure of the time field to show 10 minute increments be the correct way to move forward?

Comment: Sounds like a good option, editing the DOM. Their API looks really limited and seems to defeat their "no code application" approach. If you're comfortable with JS you could try react native and if you want a gui look at https://laska.io/

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, this is probably possible by editing the DOM, but not the best option since the customization may not work after any update.

As an alternative or a better choice, you can create two drop-down fields, "hour" on one of the them and "minute" on the other field.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Yuzo

I tried out your solution to see what it's like, and found out it was actually a good alternative.
I currently have it working with the 24 hour clock format, as below.

[gif image of customization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaq85.gif)

```
(function() {
   "use strict";
   // "hours" -> field code of Hours field
   // "minutes" -> field code of Minutes field
   // "time" -> field code of Time field
    kintone.events.on(['app.record.create.submit','app.record.edit.submit','app.record.index.edit.submit'], function (event) {
      var hourvalue = event.record.hours.value;
      var minutevalue = event.record.minutes.value;
      event.record.time.value = hourvalue + ":" + minutevalue;
      return event;
   });
})();
```

My team prefers to work with 12 hour clock format though, so I added in a radio button field to represent AM and PM. I also changed the drop down to only include selections from  0 to 11.

I edited my code a bit more so that the selected hour number will get a +12 before being entered into the time field, but I keep getting an error, "event.record['time'].value is invalid.". Not really sure why this should be happening. This is my new code:

```
(function() {
   "use strict";
   // "hours" -> field code of Hours field
   // "minutes" -> field code of Minutes field
   // "time" -> field code of Time field
   // "ampm" -> field code of radio button field that has selections of AM and PM

   kintone.events.on(['app.record.create.submit','app.record.edit.submit','app.record.index.edit.submit'], function (event) {
      var hourvalue = event.record.hours.value;
      var minutevalue = event.record.minutes.value;

      if (event.record.ampm.value == "PM"){
         hourvalue = hourvalue + 12;
      }

   event.record.time.value = hourvalue + ":" + minutevalue;
   return event;
   });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some test regarding what you are doing.
It seems like the error you are seeing appears only when the field type that you are returning
to in the script does not match the actual field type that you have placed in the form.

So I assume when you changed your form to make it as the 12 o'clock format,
you might have changed the field that you put the value into to a time field,
which before it was a text field.

Can you check into it?

I will put a link below regarding the field types just for your reference

- kintone developer network - Field Types
     https://developer.kintone.io/hc/en-us/articles/212494818-Field-Types

Comment: I only changed the dropdown options. The "Time" field I place my final value into has not changed. It has always been a time field, and still is a timefield.

Answer (score 0):

I think the drop-down field returns a string value. 
Therefore, you need to convert it to a number by using parseInt function before hourvalue like hourvalue(hourvalue + 12). Thanks.

Comment: Oh whoops, I was adding a string to a number.
It works now after I converted the drop-down value into a number. Thanks!